# Para que serve a função error do ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

tenho algumas duvidas, para que serve o error do ajax?

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'ws/controller/sys_controller.php?id=4',
            type: 'post',
            data: dados,
            success: function (data) {
                /*$("#loading").hide();
                $('#message').html('');
                $("#message").append(data);
                $("#message").show( "puff", { times:3, distance:100, direction:'down' }, 2000 ).delay(5000).hide( "puff", { times:3, distance:100, direction:'down' }, 5000 );*/
                null;
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                alert(request.responseText);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Serve para que se houver falha na requisição com o backend você tenha um escopo de tratamento de erros permitindo fornecer um feedback para a interface do cliente.

A função recebe três argumentos:

> Request que é o propio objeto jqXHR permitindo efetuar nova requisição
>   ajax ou usar os métodos internos desse objeto.
>
> Status pode receber os seguintes valores além de null, pode retornar
>   com **"timeout"**, **"error"**, **"abort"**, e **"parsererror"**
>
> Erro que se refere a mensagem de erro referente ao httpd status que
>   ocorreu no servidor, como  **"Não encontrado"** ou **"Erro interno do
>   servidor"**

Com isso você pode estabelecer um algorítimo de tratamento de erros (**exceptions**) que forneça informações mais detalhadas do problema ao usúario ou administrador.

Você pode consultar e adiquirir um conhecimento mais detalhado na documentação nesta página: [Jquery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)